# Chipset unkown - airmon-ng

Tags: wireless, networking

```
root@ubuntu:~# airmon-ng

Interface   Chipset     Driver

mon0        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
mon1        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
mon2        Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]

root@ubuntu:~# iwconfig
mon0      IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

mon1      IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

mon2      IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you ran

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

to get your mon0-2 monitor channels.

The problem you have now it that you ran the above command 3 times and not just once.
first stop mon1 and 2 by running

```
sudo airmon-ng stop mon1
sudo airmon-ng stop mon2
```

Now depending on what you want to do you'll need to chose wlan0 or mon0.
If you simply want to monitor your wifi box you'll need to chose mon0. If you actually want to affect your wifi connection you'll need to chose wlan0.

Your next problem is that you haven't installed the correct drivers for your chipset that work with airmon-ng (if there are any at all. Airmon-ng doesn't support every chipset). You can get it to work without the correct airmon-ng drivers but your mon0 will be set to the -1 channel.

Instructions on how to determine and install the correct airmon-ng drivers for your chipset can be found [here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards).

I would normally include the instructions here but they are several pages long so I decided against that.